# ItemReader could not be destroyed

Tags: spring-batch

I have created ItemReader like this:

```
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Student> getStudent() {
    JdbcCursorItemReader <Student> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setSql(QueryConstants.getStudent);   
    reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Student.class)); 
    return reader;  
}
```

However, My Spring Batch project's log showed the WARN:

```
    main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter : Destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'getStudent' threw an exception: org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Error while closing item reader
```

and there is a WARN LOG when I debugged:

```
 org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Error while closing item reader
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:142)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:339)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:273)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1029)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:494)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(ProxyConnection.java:393)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doClose(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:402)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:139)
```

Are there any problems with my ItemReader?

Comment: please share stack-trace.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your item reader definition. Since this is a warning, it is probably safe to ignore. If the issue happens consistently, please share the code that reproduces it and I will try to take a look.

Comment: Had a similar warning with a JpaPagingItemReader - changed the @Bean annotation to @Bean(destroyMethod=""). I think this could be just hiding the warning though.